# codding optimization in java

Tags: java, optimization

hello i'm starting with java and i have to make a simulation of a rabbit population on 20 years and i barely passed the sixth year, can anyone help me please to optimize my program ?

it's in French but the first loop is for the months then I'll grow my rabbits and remove the dead ones

the next for the new born babies

if you need more details about the rabbit class tell me.

Ps i've already deleted a for loop.

thanks

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        MTRandom MT = new MTRandom();
        int nbMales;
        int nbFemales;
        int nbAnnee;

        int[] init = {0x123, 0x234, 0x345, 0x456};
        MT.setSeed(init);

        //Bloc d'entrée
        ArrayList<Rabbit> Rabbits = new ArrayList<>();//changer pour linked ?

        System.out.println("Nombre de lapins males ?"); //creation males
        nbMales = input.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Nombre de lapins femelles ?");// creation femelles
        nbFemales = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Nombre d'année que va durer la simu ?");
        nbAnnee = input.nextInt();

        //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            //Rabbits.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < nbMales; i++) {
                Rabbits.add(new Rabbit('m', 12, true));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nbFemales; i++) {
                Rabbits.add(new Rabbit('f', 12, true));
            }


            //Bloc Principale
            for (int i = 1; i <= nbAnnee * 12; i++) { // Defilement des Mois
                for (int k = 0; k < Rabbits.size(); k++) {
                    Rabbits.get(k).setAge(); // incrementation de l'age des lapins en mois
                    Rabbits.removeIf(rabbit -> !rabbit.isAlive);
                    Rabbits.trimToSize();
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < Rabbits.size(); k++) { // boucle pour les projenitures
                    if (Rabbits.get(k).sexe == 'f' && Rabbits.get(k).isActiveSex && Rabbits.get(k).nbPortee > 0) {
                            double y = MT.nextDouble();

                            int n = 0;
                            if (y <= 0.3) {
                                n = 4;
                            }
                            if (y > 0.3 && y <= 0.5) {
                                n = 3;
                            }
                            if (y > 0.5 && y <= 0.7) {
                                n = 5;
                            }
                            if (y > 0.7 && y <= 0.85) {
                                n = 2;
                            }
                            if (y > 0.85) {
                                n = 6;
                            }

                            for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {

                                double x = MT.nextDouble();
                                if (x <= 0.5) {

                                    Rabbits.add(new Rabbit('m', 0, false));
                                    Rabbits.get(k).setPortee();
                                } else if (x > 0.5) {

                                    Rabbits.add(new Rabbit('f', 0, false));
                                    Rabbits.get(k).setPortee();
                                }
                            }

                    }
                    if (i % 12 == 0) {
                        Rabbits.get(k).reinitPortee();
                        Rabbits.get(k).setChanceSurvie();
                        Rabbits.get(k).kill();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("month " + i%12 + " year " + i/12 + " we have " + Rabbits.size()); // affichage chaque mois
            }
            System.out.println("Apres une simulation de " + nbAnnee + " nous avons :"); //affichage resultat final
            System.out.println("    une population de " + Rabbits.size());
    }
    //}

}
```

Rabbit Class

```java
package com.company;

public class Rabbit {
    //Age
    int ageMois;
    int ageAnnee;
    boolean isMature;
    boolean isActiveSex = false;
    double chanceSurvie = 0.5;
    boolean isAlive = true;

    //Les femelles
    boolean isSterile = false;
    char sexe;
    int nbPortee = 0;
    int nbPorteeInit;


    MTRandom MT = new MTRandom();


    public Rabbit(char sexe, int ageMois,boolean isMature){
        int[] init ={0x123, 0x234, 0x345, 0x456};
        MT.setSeed(init);

        this.sexe = sexe;
        this.ageMois = ageMois;
        this.isMature = isMature;
        double x = MT.nextDouble();
        double y = MT.nextDouble();
        if(this.sexe == 'f'){
            if(x<0.1){
                this.isSterile = true;
            }
            if(!this.isSterile){
                if(y<=0.4){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 6;
                }
                if(y>0.4 && y<=0.6){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 5;
                }
                if(y>0.6 && y<=0.8){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 7;
                }
                if(y>0.8 && y<=0.875){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 4;
                }
                if(y>0.95&& y<=0.975){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 8;
                }
                if(y>975){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 3;
                }
                if(y>975){
                    this.nbPorteeInit = 9;
                }
                this.nbPortee = this.nbPorteeInit;
            }


        }
    }

    public void setAge(){ //en mois
        double x = MT.nextDouble();

        this.ageMois += 1;
        this.ageAnnee = this.ageMois/12;

        if(this.ageMois == 5) {
            if (x <= 0.2) {
                isMature = true;
                if(!isSterile){
                isActiveSex = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(this.ageMois == 6){
            if (x >0.2 && x <= 0.5){
                isMature = true;
                if(!isSterile){
                isActiveSex = true;}
            }
        }
        else if(this.ageMois == 7){
            if(x > 0.5 && x <= 0.8){
                isMature = true;
                if(!isSterile){
                isActiveSex = true;}
            }
        }
        else if(this.ageMois > 8){
            if(x > 0.8){
                isMature = true;
                isActiveSex = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setChanceSurvie(){

        if(this.isMature){
            this.chanceSurvie = 0.75;
        }
        switch(this.ageAnnee){
            case 8: this.chanceSurvie = 0.6;
            case 9: this.chanceSurvie = 0.45;
            case 10: this.chanceSurvie = 0.3;
            case 11: this.chanceSurvie = 0.15;
            case 12: this.chanceSurvie = 0;
        }
    }
    public void setPortee(){
        this.nbPortee -=1;
    }

    public void reinitPortee(){
            this.nbPortee = this.nbPorteeInit;
    }

    public void kill(){

        if(MT.nextDouble() >this.chanceSurvie){
            isAlive = false;
        }

        }
    }
```

5 years experience

```java
month 1 year 0 we have 6
month 2 year 0 we have 11
month 3 year 0 we have 11
month 4 year 0 we have 11
month 5 year 0 we have 11
month 6 year 0 we have 20
month 7 year 0 we have 39
month 8 year 0 we have 45
month 9 year 0 we have 45
month 10 year 0 we have 45
month 11 year 0 we have 58
month 0 year 1 we have 116
month 1 year 1 we have 20
month 2 year 1 we have 33
month 3 year 1 we have 39
month 4 year 1 we have 39
month 5 year 1 we have 39
month 6 year 1 we have 69
month 7 year 1 we have 113
month 8 year 1 we have 151
month 9 year 1 we have 160
month 10 year 1 we have 164
month 11 year 1 we have 206
month 0 year 2 we have 310
month 1 year 2 we have 116
month 2 year 2 we have 160
month 3 year 2 we have 167
month 4 year 2 we have 167
month 5 year 2 we have 167
month 6 year 2 we have 366
month 7 year 2 we have 621
month 8 year 2 we have 713
month 9 year 2 we have 756
month 10 year 2 we have 758
month 11 year 2 we have 1150
month 0 year 3 we have 2032
month 1 year 3 we have 458
month 2 year 3 we have 664
month 3 year 3 we have 692
month 4 year 3 we have 692
month 5 year 3 we have 692
month 6 year 3 we have 1368
month 7 year 3 we have 2312
month 8 year 3 we have 2808
month 9 year 3 we have 2891
month 10 year 3 we have 2896
month 11 year 3 we have 4204
month 0 year 4 we have 7320
month 1 year 4 we have 1858
month 2 year 4 we have 2604
month 3 year 4 we have 2653
month 4 year 4 we have 2653
month 5 year 4 we have 2653
month 6 year 4 we have 5456
month 7 year 4 we have 9401
month 8 year 4 we have 11077
month 9 year 4 we have 11303
month 10 year 4 we have 11321
month 11 year 4 we have 17109
month 0 year 5 we have 29899
```

MT => Pseudo Random Numbers generator:

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author David Beaumont, Copyright 2005
 * <p>
 * A Java implementation of the MT19937 (Mersenne Twister) pseudo
 * random number generator algorithm based upon the original C code
 * by Makoto Matsumoto and Takuji Nishimura (see
 * <a href="http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html">
 * http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html</a> for
 * more information.
 * <p>
 * As a subclass of java.util.Random this class provides a single
 * canonical method next() for generating bits in the pseudo random
 * number sequence.  Anyone using this class should invoke the public
 * inherited methods (nextInt(), nextFloat etc.) to obtain values as
 * normal.  This class should provide a drop-in replacement for the
 * standard implementation of java.util.Random with the additional
 * advantage of having a far longer period and the ability to use a
 * far larger seed value.
 * <p>
 * This is <b>not</b> a cryptographically strong source of randomness
 * and should <b>not</b> be used for cryptographic systems or in any
 * other situation where true random numbers are required.
 * <p>
 * <!-- Creative Commons License -->
 * <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/"><img alt="CC-GNU LGPL" border="0" src="http://creativecommons.org/images/public/cc-LGPL-a.png" /></a><br />
 * This software is licensed under the <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/">CC-GNU LGPL</a>.
 * <!-- /Creative Commons License -->
 *
 * <!--
 * <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://web.resource.org/cc/"
 *     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 *     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 *
 * <Work rdf:about="">
 *    <license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/" />
 *    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Software" />
 * </Work>
 *
 * <License rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/">
 *    <permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Reproduction" />
 *    <permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Distribution" />
 *    <requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Notice" />
 *    <permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/DerivativeWorks" />
 *    <requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/ShareAlike" />
 *    <requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/SourceCode" />
 * </License>
 *
 * </rdf:RDF>
 * -->
 *
 */
public class MTRandom extends Random {

    /**
     * Auto-generated serial version UID.  Note that MTRandom does NOT
     * support serialisation of its internal state and it may even be
     * necessary to implement read/write methods to re-seed it properly.
     * This is only here to make Eclipse shut up about it being missing.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -515082678588212038L;

    // Constants used in the original C implementation
    private final static int UPPER_MASK = 0x80000000;
    private final static int LOWER_MASK = 0x7fffffff;

    private final static int N = 624;
    private final static int M = 397;
    private final static int MAGIC[] = { 0x0, 0x9908b0df };
    private final static int MAGIC_FACTOR1 = 1812433253;
    private final static int MAGIC_FACTOR2 = 1664525;
    private final static int MAGIC_FACTOR3 = 1566083941;
    private final static int MAGIC_MASK1   = 0x9d2c5680;
    private final static int MAGIC_MASK2   = 0xefc60000;
    private final static int MAGIC_SEED    = 19650218;
    private final static long DEFAULT_SEED = 5489L;

    // Internal state
    private transient int[] mt;
    private transient int mti;
    private transient boolean compat = false;

    // Temporary buffer used during setSeed(long)
    private transient int[] ibuf;

    /**
     * The default constructor for an instance of MTRandom.  This invokes
     * the no-argument constructor for java.util.Random which will result
     * in the class being initialised with a seed value obtained by calling
     * System.currentTimeMillis().
     */
    public MTRandom() { }

    /**
     * This version of the constructor can be used to implement identical
     * behaviour to the original C code version of this algorithm including
     * exactly replicating the case where the seed value had not been set
     * prior to calling genrand_int32.
     * <p>
     * If the compatibility flag is set to true, then the algorithm will be
     * seeded with the same default value as was used in the original C
     * code.  Furthermore the setSeed() method, which must take a 64 bit
     * long value, will be limited to using only the lower 32 bits of the
     * seed to facilitate seamless migration of existing C code into Java
     * where identical behaviour is required.
     * <p>
     * Whilst useful for ensuring backwards compatibility, it is advised
     * that this feature not be used unless specifically required, due to
     * the reduction in strength of the seed value.
     *
     * @param compatible Compatibility flag for replicating original
     * behaviour.
     */
    public MTRandom(boolean compatible) {
        super(0L);
        compat = compatible;
        setSeed(compat?DEFAULT_SEED:System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    /**
     * This version of the constructor simply initialises the class with
     * the given 64 bit seed value.  For a better random number sequence
     * this seed value should contain as much entropy as possible.
     *
     * @param seed The seed value with which to initialise this class.
     */
    public MTRandom(long seed) {
        super(seed);
    }

    /**
     * This version of the constructor initialises the class with the
     * given byte array.  All the data will be used to initialise this
     * instance.
     *
     * @param buf The non-empty byte array of seed information.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the buffer is null.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the buffer has zero length.
     */
    public MTRandom(byte[] buf) {
        super(0L);
        setSeed(buf);
    }

    /**
     * This version of the constructor initialises the class with the
     * given integer array.  All the data will be used to initialise
     * this instance.
     *
     * @param buf The non-empty integer array of seed information.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the buffer is null.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the buffer has zero length.
     */
    public MTRandom(int[] buf) {
        super(0L);
        setSeed(buf);
    }

    // Initializes mt[N] with a simple integer seed. This method is
    // required as part of the Mersenne Twister algorithm but need
    // not be made public.
    private final void setSeed(int seed) {

        // Annoying runtime check for initialisation of internal data
        // caused by java.util.Random invoking setSeed() during init.
        // This is unavoidable because no fields in our instance will
        // have been initialised at this point, not even if the code
        // were placed at the declaration of the member variable.
        if (mt == null) mt = new int[N];

        // ---- Begin Mersenne Twister Algorithm ----
        mt[0] = seed;
        for (mti = 1; mti < N; mti++) {
            mt[mti] = (MAGIC_FACTOR1 * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >>> 30)) + mti);
        }
        // ---- End Mersenne Twister Algorithm ----
    }

    /**
     * This method resets the state of this instance using the 64
     * bits of seed data provided.  Note that if the same seed data
     * is passed to two different instances of MTRandom (both of
     * which share the same compatibility state) then the sequence
     * of numbers generated by both instances will be identical.
     * <p>
     * If this instance was initialised in 'compatibility' mode then
     * this method will only use the lower 32 bits of any seed value
     * passed in and will match the behaviour of the original C code
     * exactly with respect to state initialisation.
     *
     * @param seed The 64 bit value used to initialise the random
     * number generator state.
     */
    public final synchronized void setSeed(long seed) {
        if (compat) {
            setSeed((int)seed);
        } else {

            // Annoying runtime check for initialisation of internal data
            // caused by java.util.Random invoking setSeed() during init.
            // This is unavoidable because no fields in our instance will
            // have been initialised at this point, not even if the code
            // were placed at the declaration of the member variable.
            if (ibuf == null) ibuf = new int[2];

            ibuf[0] = (int)seed;
            ibuf[1] = (int)(seed >>> 32);
            setSeed(ibuf);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method resets the state of this instance using the byte
     * array of seed data provided.  Note that calling this method
     * is equivalent to calling "setSeed(pack(buf))" and in particular
     * will result in a new integer array being generated during the
     * call.  If you wish to retain this seed data to allow the pseudo
     * random sequence to be restarted then it would be more efficient
     * to use the "pack()" method to convert it into an integer array
     * first and then use that to re-seed the instance.  The behaviour
     * of the class will be the same in both cases but it will be more
     * efficient.
     *
     * @param buf The non-empty byte array of seed information.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the buffer is null.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the buffer has zero length.
     */
    public final void setSeed(byte[] buf) {
        setSeed(pack(buf));
    }

    /**
     * This method resets the state of this instance using the integer
     * array of seed data provided.  This is the canonical way of
     * resetting the pseudo random number sequence.
     *
     * @param buf The non-empty integer array of seed information.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the buffer is null.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the buffer has zero length.
     */
    public final synchronized void setSeed(int[] buf) {
        int length = buf.length;
        if (length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seed buffer may not be empty");
        // ---- Begin Mersenne Twister Algorithm ----
        int i = 1, j = 0, k = (N > length ? N : length);
        setSeed(MAGIC_SEED);
        for (; k > 0; k--) {
            mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i-1] ^ (mt[i-1] >>> 30)) * MAGIC_FACTOR2)) + buf[j] + j;
            i++; j++;
            if (i >= N) { mt[0] = mt[N-1]; i = 1; }
            if (j >= length) j = 0;
        }
        for (k = N-1; k > 0; k--) {
            mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i-1] ^ (mt[i-1] >>> 30)) * MAGIC_FACTOR3)) - i;
            i++;
            if (i >= N) { mt[0] = mt[N-1]; i = 1; }
        }
        mt[0] = UPPER_MASK; // MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array
        // ---- End Mersenne Twister Algorithm ----
    }

    /**
     * This method forms the basis for generating a pseudo random number
     * sequence from this class.  If given a value of 32, this method
     * behaves identically to the genrand_int32 function in the original
     * C code and ensures that using the standard nextInt() function
     * (inherited from Random) we are able to replicate behaviour exactly.
     * <p>
     * Note that where the number of bits requested is not equal to 32
     * then bits will simply be masked out from the top of the returned
     * integer value.  That is to say that:
     * <pre>
     * mt.setSeed(12345);
     * int foo = mt.nextInt(16) + (mt.nextInt(16) << 16);</pre>
     * will not give the same result as
     * <pre>
     * mt.setSeed(12345);
     * int foo = mt.nextInt(32);</pre>
     *
     * @param bits The number of significant bits desired in the output.
     * @return The next value in the pseudo random sequence with the
     * specified number of bits in the lower part of the integer.
     */
    protected final synchronized int next(int bits) {
        // ---- Begin Mersenne Twister Algorithm ----
        int y, kk;
        if (mti >= N) {             // generate N words at one time

            // In the original C implementation, mti is checked here
            // to determine if initialisation has occurred; if not
            // it initialises this instance with DEFAULT_SEED (5489).
            // This is no longer necessary as initialisation of the
            // Java instance must result in initialisation occurring
            // Use the constructor MTRandom(true) to enable backwards
            // compatible behaviour.

            for (kk = 0; kk < N-M; kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk] & UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk+1] & LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk+M] ^ (y >>> 1) ^ MAGIC[y & 0x1];
            }
            for (;kk < N-1; kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk] & UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk+1] & LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk+(M-N)] ^ (y >>> 1) ^ MAGIC[y & 0x1];
            }
            y = (mt[N-1] & UPPER_MASK) | (mt[0] & LOWER_MASK);
            mt[N-1] = mt[M-1] ^ (y >>> 1) ^ MAGIC[y & 0x1];

            mti = 0;
        }

        y = mt[mti++];

        // Tempering
        y ^= (y >>> 11);
        y ^= (y << 7) & MAGIC_MASK1;
        y ^= (y << 15) & MAGIC_MASK2;
        y ^= (y >>> 18);
        // ---- End Mersenne Twister Algorithm ----
        return (y >>> (32-bits));
    }

    // This is a fairly obscure little code section to pack a
    // byte[] into an int[] in little endian ordering.

    /**
     * This simply utility method can be used in cases where a byte
     * array of seed data is to be used to repeatedly re-seed the
     * random number sequence.  By packing the byte array into an
     * integer array first, using this method, and then invoking
     * setSeed() with that; it removes the need to re-pack the byte
     * array each time setSeed() is called.
     * <p>
     * If the length of the byte array is not a multiple of 4 then
     * it is implicitly padded with zeros as necessary.  For example:
     * <pre>    byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 }</pre>
     * becomes
     * <pre>    int[]  { 0x04030201, 0x00000605 }</pre>
     * <p>
     * Note that this method will not complain if the given byte array
     * is empty and will produce an empty integer array, but the
     * setSeed() method will throw an exception if the empty integer
     * array is passed to it.
     *
     * @param buf The non-null byte array to be packed.
     * @return A non-null integer array of the packed bytes.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the given byte array is null.
     */
    public static int[] pack(byte[] buf) {
        int k, blen = buf.length, ilen = ((buf.length+3) >>> 2);
        int[] ibuf = new int[ilen];
        for (int n = 0; n < ilen; n++) {
            int m = (n+1) << 2;
            if (m > blen) m = blen;
            for (k = buf[--m]&0xff; (m & 0x3) != 0; k = (k << 8) | buf[--m]&0xff);
            ibuf[n] = k;
        }
        return ibuf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the population of the rabbits as your simulation is being executed. I would guess that there might be an exponential increase, which leads to too many rabbits for the simulation to handle.

Comment: what can I do to handle that please ? because the numbers are correct and except delete the dead I don't know what to do.

Comment: may i can change for an array instead of a list ??

Comment: Can you post the numbers? I don't think changing the ArrayList to a dynamic array will help.

Comment: I added the rabbit class and a test with 5 years
thank you

Comment: Can you post what MTRandom is?
I was hoping to be able to run the code.
Also, is `Rabbits.get(k).dead();` supposed to be `Rabbits.get(k).kill();`

Comment: You never `break;` in you switch statement in `setChanceSurvie()`. Try adding a break after every case.

Comment: i aded the MT class meanwhile I'll check the cases

Comment: yes I changed dead() to kill() after posting but it's correct in my version thanks

Comment: I tried this code, but didn't get the output that you got:
`Nombre de lapins males ?
10
Nombre de lapins femelles ?
10
Nombre d'année que va durer la simu ?
10
Au mois 0 de l'annee 0 nous avons 65
Au mois 1 de l'annee 0 nous avons 0
Au mois 2 de l'annee 0 nous avons 0
Au mois 3 de l'annee 0 nous avons 0
Au mois 4 de l'annee 0 nous avons 0
...
 Apres une simulation de 10 nous avons :
    une population de 0
        dont 0 lapins males
        et 0 lapin femelles`

Comment: I think It’s normal because of the pseudo random number generator

Comment: I changed the main it will work now it works for me but it's always too slow